# Resolving an online SBT dependency with "." characters in path

Tags: scala, sbt

In my project I want to use the `sbinary` library to (de)serialize some case classes to a binary form. I also want to use the latest Scala in the project. Typesafe offers [a version of `sbinary`](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org.scala-tools.sbinary/sbinary_2.11/0.4.2/) in their repositories, and they seem to be the only one who are doing so.

So I add the repository and dependency to my `build.sbt` like so:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-tools.sbinary" %% "sbinary" % "0.4.2"
```

Surprisingly, this fails. With a dependency defined like this, SBT tries to find the dependency at the url `http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scala-tools/sbinary/sbinary_2.11.0` whereas it is really located at `http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org.scala-tools.sbinary/sbinary_2.11.0`. Because SBT replaces the dots in the dependency group id with slashes, it is not able to find the dependency in the place it's in.

I've tried some tricks for building the string in other ways, but they are all useless since SBT replaces the `.`s by `/`s in the string after it is evaluated. How can I get SBT to find the dependency at this URL?

Please note that I'm aware that I could simply make this an offline dependency, but I'd prefer to have this build script work out of the box on any computer with SBT installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org.scala-tools.sbinary/sbinary_2.11.0` is in ivy style. The default style of sbt is maven2 so your resolver doesn't work.

try

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("Typesafe Repository (ivy)", url("http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/TY1AoYYvB4k